# Eclipse JSF content assist complete failure

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, jsf

So I have JSF running on a tomcat app server in eclipse, this has been very troublesome so far.

The bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=192393

First, eclipse won't let me install libraries for JSF when adding the facet, so I had to manually download and add as a facet. This works fine after a lot of modification.

But I can not get content assist to work in .xhtml files, I've tried all solutions, none worked. If I rename to JSP it works, so it's not the TLDs. But if I make *.jsp the default faces servlet url pattern, it messes everything up for obvious reasons. I've been developing with 0 content assist, which is fine but I'd rather have it to save time.

I tried all solutions I found online

Eclipse Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
JSF: 2.2.9 API + IMPL as custom added facet library using sun.com.faces (majorra)
Tomcat 9
JSTL 1.1

I've tried:

-Changing from JSF facet to maven dependency based.
-Adding *.XHTML to JSP content types
-Adding JSP editor to XHTML content type 
-Adding TLDs to web-inf/TLDs
-Adding JSF libs as recource
-Changing from Jaxax.faces to com.sun.faces API/IMPL libraries
-Changing pages to JSPX and JSP from XHTML
-Adding a .XHTML as default file type for JSF in web config

The problem lies in eclipses code assist, It considers XHTML as an HTML file, and HTML does not have any XML content assist, or jsp content assist. I'd like to know if there is a way to "add" code assist proposals to all html files so it acts as if it's JSP.

My other option was to get .xhtml parsed as a jsp file type (but I can't do this, it's all locked in) and I feel this may create the same issue as if I was running a .jsp on a faces servlet.

So does anybody know a workaround to add content assist proposals? Or a better way?

Thank you!

Comment: Which "all solutions" do you mean? Which version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: I tried all solutions i found online

I added more details to main question

Comment: The bug you are referring was fixed many years ago. Probably you mean bug 339127, which refers to a [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20111112133435/http://workflow.imixs.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/eclipse_helios_jsf_content_assist) with a solution to your problem. I can understand that it is sometimes frustrating when functions are not where you expect them to be. But it does not make sense to tell the open source authors that it's a huge mistake to use their software, from whom you'd like get an answer on how their software works.

Comment: My mistake was setting up java ee features in a tomcat app server with eclipse. Tomcat is not a java ee server, and eclipses ee repos are broken. I think we can all agree on this. I love eclipse, i do not love java ee features in tomcat+eclipse.  They know the repos are broken. My statement is not for the authors, it is so people dont make the same mistake i did and use a better stack. I would never complain to an open source dev.

But in my list i did already attempted this fix, I am  already loading with jsp editor. However i will try pulling jars from glassfish as it suggests.

Comment: You **_can't_** use java-ee in Tomcat since it is not a java-ee container. I never ever had problems with wildfly and eclipse (and maven) for java-ee projects (but I also always added jboss tools as a great addition). The transition to 'eclipse-ee' might play a role here and that has to iron itself out. Tge 'rant' is indeed not a great incentive to get help

Comment: From my understanding tomcat can handle certain EE 'features' when properly configured, i didnt need full blown EE. regardless its a bad idea, you're right. I switched to intellij and life is good now. However if you consider saying "using eclipse for java EE with tomcat was a HUGE mistake" a rant, then i have lost hope. My hope is others wont make the same mistake, im less worried about help for myself. The switch to intellij took me 5 minutes, no additional config, its flawless. The first guy has a YT around eclipse,but you surprised me with that comment. Eclipse has its place, its not here.